# Can't map Many-to-Many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two objects, **User** and **Room** both of which inherit from a **Base** Object.

```
class BaseModel:
    __metaclass__ = Serializable

    created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    modified = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()


Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseModel)
```

This is my **User** model with the many-to-many association with Room declared on top.

```
association_table = Table('users_rooms', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')),
    Column('room_id', Integer, ForeignKey('room.id'))
)
class User(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    mobile = Column(String(20), index=True, unique=True)
    rooms = relationship("Room", secondary=association_table, 
    back_populates="users")
```

And this is the **Room** model.

```
association_table = Table('users_rooms', Base.metadata,
                          Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')),
                          Column('room_id', Integer, ForeignKey('room.id'))
                          )


class Room(Base):

    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    room_type = Column(String(50), default=RoomType.PRIVATE)
    hex_code = Column(String(100), unique=True)
     users = relationship("User", secondary=association_table, back_populates="rooms")
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'users_rooms' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is trying to tell you that you do not need to – and shouldn't – define the association table in both modules. Define it in one of them, or in a module of its own, and either import it, or refer to it lazily in `relationship()` using `secondary="users_rooms"`:

```
# Room model. Note the absence of `association_table`

class Room(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    room_type = Column(String(50), default=RoomType.PRIVATE)
    hex_code = Column(String(100), unique=True)
    users = relationship("User", secondary="users_rooms", back_populates="rooms")
```

The table name as a string value passed in [`secondary=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.secondary) is looked up from the `MetaData` collection associated with the `Room` model.

You also should not need to sprinkle

```
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

in your models. If you get errors similar to the one in this question without it, the tables have already been created and included in the `MetaData` collection before your models are constructed. You may have used reflection, for example.

Comment: Worked like a charm.